# Can anyone identify these two Lego parts? White ramp and yellow door

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

Bought a big bundle of parts recently, two of which I'm struggling to identify and load onto Rebrickable.

Can anybody assist?

[image]

Comment: That yellow door doesn't look like a Lego part. More like a door from the loading bay on some truck-model. Oh wait... I just see that that is already said in another answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what the yellow piece is, but the big plate is an old 1955-69 garage floor plate, with the rectangular holes.

[Garage Floor Plate (Old style)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=820)

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this. There is also a slightly different version (nr 820a) of this plate which has a narrower lip at the bottom of the slope and octagon holes (that is the one I have). The garage doors have spring that comes under tension when you close them. The lip blocks the doors from opening. Press the lip with your fingertip and the doors will spring open en the car rolls down the ramp and leaves the garage. It was pretty amazing back in the 1970's when I got this for my birthday.

Answer (score 3):

The yellow part looks like the hatch door of an older Siku Truck [like this one in eBay](https://m.ebay.at/itm/Siku-1-55-2919-3520-Mercedes-SK-Sattelkipper-Meyer-Co-B9212-/122430097173?nav=SEARCH)

Comment: That ebay link won't last for long.  Could you add a screenshot to your answer?

Comment: @chicks unfortunately i don't have an Image at hand. Everithing i can find in Google links total eBay or similar Pages. I'll have an Look at this Ehen i'm at Home.

Comment: @Syberion I don't think it's a god idea to steal copyrighted images from eBay. I therefore removed the Image again.